# media3 SimpleBasicPlayer handleSetPlayWhenReady

Tags: android, android-media3

I'm implementing a MediaLibraryService, with my own player that based on SimpleBasicPlayer.    My class, that's derived from SimpleBasicPlayer, implements handleSetPlayWhenReady.    I see handleSetPlayWhenReady gets called when I expect.   But the state is never updated.  I'm not setting it myself.  I'm returning Futures.immediateVoidFuture() from handleSetPlayWhenReady. Looking at the source in SimpleBasicPlayer, it looks SimpleBasicPlayer isn't settings the state when I return Futures.immediateVoidFuture(), but would if I returned ????? That's really my question, what should I return to get SimpleBasicPlayer to handle the set change.